# Do canceled Futures in Rust stop at non-await points?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future

When a running future is cancelled from another thread, will it interrupt the execution of code, or continue until it hits an await point to stop?

```rust
async fn hellos() {
    use tokio::time::*;

    for i in 0..500 {
        // if i get canceled, will i ever stop here?
        println!("Hello {i}!");
    }
    
    // or wait until this
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;

    
    for i in 0..500 {
        // same thing
        println!("Hello {}!", i + 500);
    }

    // and here too
}
```

Comment: Only await points.

Comment: No, although an edge case is futures cancelled by returning from `main`, if your executor doesn't wait for all futures to complete on it's `Drop` impl. In that case, the thread running those futures can die at any point, not just await points.